# SVG sprite: how to handle sizes?

Tags: svg, sprite

I am searching for a good solution to work with SVG Sprites.

Currently I have a folder of svg files, with [grunt-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-svg-sprite) I get a SVG sprite image and a CSS File with background image definitions.

Now I want to replace my single-file SVGs with the sprite SVG, but I cant resize them. Some of them are not in the correct size in the original file.  I tried lots of combinations with width, height, background size, without success.

Here is the CSS with single file SVG for a list item with a checkbox image:

```
li {
   background-image: url(../../img/check_red.svg);
   background-position: 0 12px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 16px auto;
   padding-left: 26px;
}
```

How to do this with a sprite SVG?

I need a solution with some kind of automation: new SVG files are added after running a task, SVGs have different sizes, and so on. 
What I tried already and did not work was [grunt-svgstore](https://github.com/FWeinb/grunt-svgstore), the SVG images were messed up (changed shapes, lines, colors)

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach here:

```
.icon-clock {
  background: url("sprite.svg#svgView(viewBox(0, 0, 32, 32))") no-repeat;
}
```

I did not test it but it allows you to define the viewbox inside the background.

(Source: https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: But how to use it with CSS, like in my CSS example with list items? Then I have to add a SVG tag to each list item, right? Not my preferred solution currently...

Comment: I see what you want to do now. You want to use them as "list icons". Would this approach work? (See updated answer)